# 'phpspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, testing, phpspec

I'm using Windows. I installed phpspec package with composer, I added the folder phpspec/bin/ to my system's path variable. But when I try to run **phpspec** command I get the following error:

```
'phpspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Even when I run the command directly from the bin directory where the phpspec.php is stored, I get the same error.

Comment: `phpspec.bat`? A file without extension cannot be run in windows. So it must either have `.exe` or `.bat` extension.

Answer (score 1):

unlike *nix, where you can put a [shebang](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) on top of the file to make it executable, on windows you have to run a php file with `C:\php\php filename.php` (or `php filename.php` if `php` is in your `path`), so windows won't recognize a php as executable, even though its in your path.

If you do want to be able to invoke it plainly as `phpspec`, rather than `php /path/to/phpspec/bin/phpspec.php`, then inside of the `bin` folder, make a `phpspec.bat` file with 1 line in it:

**phpspec.bat**

```
php phpspec.php %*
```

and now you should be able to run `phpspec` as a command.

Comment: It doesn't work. I created the file phpspec.bat with the content you suggested, but I still get errors when I try to run phpspec. When I run phpspec outside the bin folder I get the same error "'phpspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,". When I run it inside the bin folder where phpspec.bat is located, I get the following error: Could not open input file: phpspec.php

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder does

```
php bin\phpspec.php
```

is it work? If not what does **phpspec.php** look like i.e. is it plain php?